# How to add iOrderedQueryable results to a list?

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I'm trying to add my database results to list.  Here's my class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Tick { get; set; }
    public string Exchange { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my routine:

```
var myList = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (var element in compsList)
{       
    myList.Add(Price_tbl
    .Where(p => p.Ticker.Equals(element.Tick) && p.Tick_datetime <= DateTime.Today)
    .GroupBy(p => new { Comp = p.Ticker })
    .Select(p => new MyClass {
        Tick = p.Key.Comp,
        Exchange = element.Exchange,
        Price = p.OrderByDescending(c => c.Tick_datetime).Select(c => c.Close_price).FirstOrDefault(),
        Volume = (p.Sum(c => c.Volume) / 52),
    }));
}
```

But I'm getting the error:
`cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<UserQuery.MyClass>' to 'UserQuery.MyClass'`

Is there another way to add the results to a list? (I've been racking my brain on this for a few hours now.)

Comment: `AddRange(...)`

Comment: Ahh!  Thanks so much.  I didn't even think of looking at that.